# Impedance Equalization Circuit

Tags: impedance

With reference to the circuit on attached -- the zobel/ impedance equalization circuit. If we don't know the value of L, Is there any ways to calculate C' without knowing the value of L? I believe this story might be involved in the frequency-domain. Therefore, if we have the data of frequency response, in this case it is a loudspeaker's, such as cut-off frequency or the point where frequency starts to rise, can we use it instead? Please anyone help to explain.[image]

Comment: You need to measure L or something equivalent, because that's exactly what the C' is intended to compensate, so I'm not quite sure: Is your question A) "can I find a C' without measuring?", then the answer is plain "no."; Or: is your question B) "how can I do a measurement to determine what I need to know to choose C'?", because that has a longer answer.

Comment: When both R equal \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ then the network looks resistive. You need to know L or just take a bit of a guess. These days, audio amplifiers can survive without a zobel network.

Comment: Are there any ways to convert L into the form of C, or f? Since L is hard to measure from the loudspeaker due to the dependence with frequency.

Comment: Andy aka, Could you please help to share us the math calculation that you did? Thanks in advance